# Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir) API On Mac OSX fails to use supplied environment correctly

Tags: java, macos, runtime, exec, macos-catalina

When I use **public Process exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)**  API On **Mac OSX**  (*Catalina Version 10.15.4*)  the child process is not getting the correct environment variables passed. This is bit weird that if the env[] string contains any  new environment variables defined that is passed to the child process correctly, but an existing variables value is modified and passed say for example PATH to a new value  then child process  does not get the modified value , it gets pre existing value.

Important note  **this happens only on Mac OSX,** on windows and Linux this works perfectly fine.

Below is a code snippet that I am using

```
    StringBuilder cmd = new StringBuilder();
    cmd.append("/usr/bin/open ");
    cmd.append("-F -n -a ");
    cmd.append("Terminal.app ");
    cmd.append(workingDir);
    
    String[] env = new String[5];
    env[0]= "PATH=" + "/home/xxtest/temp"+ ":" + System.getenv("PATH");
    env[1]= "SYSTEM=" + "/home/xxtest/install/testsystem";
    env[2]= "CORE=" + "testcore";
 
    try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.toString(),env,workingDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
    }
```

Now when terminal app is opened and if I check the env variables

```
mac-jup4:onp6 poonamg$ printenv
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMPDIR=/var/folders/1l/4vsmgmmx1k364y5_j0km08006clg6j/T/
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=433
TERM_SESSION_ID=D3D3FDC1-D065-432F-BDF5-73D548AD6462
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.tWljT5bOon/Listeners
SYSTEM=/home/xxtest/install/testsys
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
CORE=testcore
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.EHe3TVLbtI/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
mac-jup4:onp6 poonamg$
```

You can see **CORE** , **SYSTEM** environment variable but **PATH** is not updated

Any clue why this happens on OSX ?

Comment: Your Terminal may be sourcing other env scripts (eg ~/.bashrc / .profile etc ...) which set PATH explicitly and override your pre-existing value passed in.

Comment: Yes , that was the reason. Wrote a script to work around it . Thanks